# JS: mouseout event on document / window

Tags: javascript

I have added `mouseout` event listener on `window` / `document` object.
I want to trigger this event when I move the cursor to an iframe in page, but it's also trigger on other elements in body.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation()
   console.log('out')
}, true)
// not working so I try adding this event to widow

window.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation()
   console.log('out')
}, true)
// not working too
```

Please help! Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

You can register your event like this:

```
document.getElementById("sa").contentDocument.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation()
   console.log('out')
}, true)
```

But you may end up with permission error if your content is cross domain.